# Kendo Grid Locked/Frozen column has a rendering issue when scrolling to the last few records

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Every time I lock/freeze the first column, I scroll down and some of the last few records in that column are not rendered.  is this a bug?  Version: v2015.1.429

[Link to rendering issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyhsU.png)

Comment: Might be a bug, just try to run same code with different version of kendo.

Comment: I tried with a 2016 version and still the same rendering issue.